# List selector state selected not working [ANDROID]

Tags: android, listview, selector, listviewitem

In my app, i am using a list view to show a list of items that have one text and one image, i have added a list selector attribute to list view so that any list item will be clicked its background color will be changed to a different one.The problem is that when the list item is selected listview's row (that is a text view and a image view) background is not changed however state pressed is working fine.How it will work?
Any help will be appreciated

**Listview**

```
<ListView
android:id="@+id/list"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="0dp"
android:layout_weight="1"
android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
android:divider="@null"
android:dividerHeight="0dp"
android:listSelector="@drawable/nav_lists_selector"
/>
```

**List Selector**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"   android:exitFadeDuration="@android:integer/config_mediumAnimTime">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/list_pressed" android:state_pressed="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/list_selected" android:state_selected="true" />
</selector>
```

**List Pressed**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle">
    <solid android:color="@color/clr_list_pressed"/>
</shape>
```

**List Selected**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle">
    <solid android:color="@color/clr_list_selected"/>
</shape>
```

Comment: Do you just want to keep highlighted the selected  item? or you also want different color for every item while selected?

Comment: I want to keep the selected item in a different color than the non selected items. The selected state and state activated is not working for this purpose so far and I have also tried adding the default state.

Answer (score 2):

Old topic but I run into the same problem. For some strange reason the `android:state_selected="true"` and `android:state_selected="false"` are reversed for me.

So what finally worked was:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:state_selected="false"
        android:drawable="@drawable/list_row_bg_selected"/>
    <item
        android:state_selected="true"
        android:drawable="@color/colorWhite"/>
</selector>
```

So now the only question is, why I have to use those two values reversed.

EDIT:

Think I find why it behaved strangely.
After I added the `android:listSelector="@drawable/list_selector"` that I used for the listview to the `android:background="@drawable/list_selector"` listview's item view the `android:state_selected="true"` and `false` work normally as one whould expect in the selector.

```
   <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/list_selector"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <....some Textviews....>
    />

    </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks, what solved for me too was explicitly determining `state_enabled=true` as well, if I just determined `state_enabled=false` and also defined a default color, some devices would invert them...

Answer (score 0):

You need add "normal status" in your **List Selector**

```
<item android:drawable="@drawable/normal_list_color_or_image" />
```

You only was added status selected and pressed, but you don't was added normal status.

"Normal status" is when your component don't have received one action.

Answer (score 0):

In `onItemclick` of `Listview` you can get the position of selected item

```
@Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapter, View arg1, int position, long id) {
                selectedItem = position;
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
```

And in the `getView()` method of adapter you can change the color of sleceted item

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    final View view = View.inflate(context, R.layout.item_list, null);

    if (position == selectedItem) {
        // Your desired color
    }

    return view;
}
```

And using selector try the below code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:state_pressed="true" 
    android:drawable="@drawable/pressed" />
<item  android:state_focused="false" 
    android:drawable="@drawable/normal" />
</selector>
```